# Parsing email message headers in Go

Tags: email, parsing, go, syntax

How I can read some headers from an email message in Go?

Usually I would use [ReadMIMEHeader()](https://golang.org/src/net/textproto/reader.go?s=12179:12232#L458), but sadly not everybody has read all the relevant RFCs and for some messages I get output like:

> malformed MIME header line: name="7DDA4_foo_9E5D72.zip"

I narrowed the culprit to be

```
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed; x-unix-mode=0600;
name="7DDA4_foo_9E5D72.zip"
```

instead of

```
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed; x-unix-mode=0600; 
  name="7DDA4_foo_9E5D72.zip"
```

in the source of the message.

[Go Playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/y4OS532H1J)

**What is the correct way of parsing the headers correctly, regardless if indented or not?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the message is malformed, I would fix it through a separate piece of code that reformats the message:

```
func fixBrokenMime(r_ io.Reader, w io.WriteCloser) {
    r := bufio.NewScanner(bufio.NewReader(r_))
    for r.Scan() {
        line := r.Text()
        if len(line) > 0 && line[0] != ' ' && strings.IndexByte(line, ':') < 0 {
            line = " " + line
        }
        w.Write([]byte(line+"\n"))
    }
    w.Close()
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/OZsXT7pmtN

Obviously, you may want a different heuristic. I assumed that a line that is not indented and doesn't contain ":", must be indented.

Comment: Although this not fixes the problem 100% (you will indent all further lines from the message body) I accept this message, because it makes the most sense to reformat the message in front before parsing. Thanks for the sugestion.

Comment: it wasn't 100% clear from your original message that the code needed to handle a full MIME message including the body. It's easy to fix it though: just stop indenting when you see an empty line. See: http://play.golang.org/p/Z_9wWW24_x

Comment: I just wanted to bring clear what I want to achieve with this simple example. Your second suggestion will not work for multipart MIME messages, but I got the idea.

Comment: I wanted to ask for a clarification in this regard. According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-2.2.3 folding with CRLF may occur in headers, am i reading this incorrectly ( because if stdlib of go does not support i think i might ).

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/sendgrid/go-gmime (disclaimer, I work with SendGrid, but did not put together anything in the lib)